# Why does my export stop updating when the array it references is sliced?

Tags: node.js, module

I've been using node.js for a few years now and generally believed that I understood how exports worked, but an edge case today has left me a bit confused. My code when simplified, behaved like the following:

a.js

```
var history = []
var  i = 0

exports.updateHistory = function(){
    history.push(i)
    i++

    if(history.length > 10){
        history = history.slice(5)
    }
}

exports.history = history
```

b.js

```
var a = require('./a')

setInterval(function(){
    a.updateHistory()
    console.log(a.history)
}, 200)
```

I expected the output of this to be the following:

```
[ 0 ]
[ 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ]
[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
[ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
[ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ]
[ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 ]
...
```

But instead, this was my output:

```
[ 0 ]
[ 0, 1 ]
[ 0, 1, 2 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
```

I was able to solve the problem by adding `exports.history = history` after it slices each time, implying that the slice call is somehow changing the export's reference, but I have no idea why this would be. Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only updating the local variable and not the exported value.

Change this:

```
exports.history = history = history.slice(5)
```

The reason this is needed is because [`array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns a *copy* of that portion of the array and that is not visible outside of the module (`exports.history` still references the original array).

Comment: I understand that `array.slice()` returns a copy, but shouldn't `exports.history` still be referencing `history`, which is now equal to this new copy?

Comment: No. With your original code the assignment only happens once, when the module is loaded.

Comment: **but shouldn't exports.history still be referencing history, which is now equal to this new copy** - No.  wrt javascript running on the browser your code would have added a new variable called `history` to window scope which would not be the same array that you had when you started executing your code. Not sure abt node though(it has a global scope too). But in any case doing a slice() would result in a new array.